# I can solve this but how can you write an expression for it that will work with any number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A company charges 8.00 to dig a hole one foot deep.  The second foot is 5.40, the third $4.32, etc.  (Note that the cost of each subsequent foot is 20% less than the previous). The question asks what it will cost to dig a hole 5 feet deep.
I can arrive at the solution alright by making a chart - but how can I write an expression and teach it to my students?

Comment: @Kaster I think a suitable runner-up to actual knowledge is the ability to ask for help, rather than the steadfast belief that your knowledge is sufficient and/or that the topic is irrelevant. Surely this is a worthy quality to teach students, as well.

Comment: So for \$40, I can have them keep digging forever? Cool!

Comment: Chart is good. I would urge that you not just fill it out with *numbers* out of a calculator. So do what you presumably did, labels first foot, second foot, and so on. In first, of course you put $8$. For second, put $\frac{80}{100}\cdot 8$, like that. For third, put $\frac{80}{100}\frac{80}{100}\cdot 8$, and maybe $\left(\frac{80}{100}\right)^2\cdot 8$. And so on. Whether you introduce formula for sum of GP is a matter of grade. If you don't, maybe provide a link for the interested. After all this, you can use the calculator to give conventional "evaluations" of the various terms.

Comment: For sum, it is probably useful to introduce at least the expression $a+aq+aq^2+aq^3+aq^4$, where $a$ serves as abbreviation for $8$, and $q$ for $80/100$.

Comment: 80% of \$8.00 is \$6.40 not \$5.40 --- does the first foot not fit the pattern, or is there a mistake in the question?

Answer (score 0):

As anon mentions, the quantity you are looking at has the form  $$a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+ar^4$$ where $a=8$ and $r=\frac{80}{100}$.  This type of series is called a *geometric series,* and there is a comprehensive [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) which provides an enormous amount of details.  In particular, you are interested in a general formula for this series.  Both the formula, and the proof for why it is true can be found in the [formula section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) of the Wikipedia page.  I have copied the relevant portion below.

> For $r\neq 1$, the sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric series is:
> $$a + ar + a r^2 + a r^3 + \cdots + a r^{n-1} = a\cdot \frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}.$$
> here $a$ is the first term of the series, and $r$ is the common ratio. We can derive this formula as follows:
> $$\text{Let }s = a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + \cdots + ar^{n-1}.$$
> $$\text{Then }rs = ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + ar^4 + \cdots + ar^{n}$$
> $$\text{Then }s - rs = a-ar^{n}$$
> $$\text{Then }s(1-r) = a(1-r^{n}),$$
> $$\text{ so }s = a \frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}.$$